# How can I navigate to a previous commit after a file has been moved?

Tags: github

If I have browsed to a file on a commit that moved the file, what is the easiest way to navigate to the previous commit and location of the file?

For example, see the [commit history on this file](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commits/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/HtmlHelper.cs).  The last entry on September 17 is the commit where the file was moved.  To find its previous location, I did the following:

1. Noted the initial commit date
2. Went to the [front page](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc)
3. Clicked on [commits](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commits/dev)
4. Paged through to September 17 and found the commit
5. Clicked on the [commit prior](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/046cb976b3e899052a95387b72ea4bee6987bff0)
6. Clicked [Browse Files](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/046cb976b3e899052a95387b72ea4bee6987bff0)
7. Hit <kbd>T</kbd> to open the [file finder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/find/046cb976b3e899052a95387b72ea4bee6987bff0)
8. Typed `HtmlHelper.cs`
9. Click the [first result](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/046cb976b3e899052a95387b72ea4bee6987bff0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/Html/HtmlHelper.cs)

Is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-follow/agalokjhnhheienloigiaoohgmjdpned) to make this far simpler.  None of the steps in the question are required any longer, as the initial page contains a link per the screenshot below.  [Source](https://github.com/staff0rd/github-follow-extension) on github.

[image: Github Follow Extension]